# How to pull debian8 (Jessie) image in Docker

Tags: docker

I wrote my Dokerfile like this :

```
system@vmdebian:~$ more Dockerfile 
FROM debian8

ENV APACHE_RUN_USER www-data
ENV APACHE_RUN_GROUP www-data
ENV APACHE_LOG_DIR /var/web/log/apache2
ENV APACHE_PID_FILE /var/run/apache2.pid
ENV APACHE_RUN_DIR /var/run/apache2
ENV APACHE_LOCK_DIR /var/lock/apache2

RUN export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive && apt-get update && apt-get -y -q upgrade && apt-get -y -q install apache2

EXPOSE 80 443

CMD ["apache2ctl","-D","FOREGROUND"]
```

When I ran This command:

```
docker image build -t dub/superapache Dockefile
```

I've got this error message :

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon  20.99kB
Step 1/10 : FROM debian8
pull access denied for debian8, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login'
```

What is the image name of Debian Jessie in Docker ?

Comment: shouldn't it be `FROM debian:jessie`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checking the [Debian Docker Hub](https://hub.docker.com/_/debian), Debian 8 is *"jessie"*.

You can pull the tag with `docker pull debian:jessie` or `docker pull debian:8`.

Change your `FROM` line to:

```
FROM debian:jessie
```

If you actually wanted Debian 6 *"squeeze"* you would have to look for a non-official source or build your own.

Comment: With `FROM debian:squeeze` works too. You're right debian6 is named squeeze `Step 1/10 : FROM debian:squeeze squeeze: Pulling from library/debian`. I corrected the post to be in phase with your answer.